# Adding links to facebook newsfeed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there anyway I can attach a link to a news feed (which was not created by my application)?

Lets say that I would like to create a "send a hug" application. So now when a user browse his news feeds he can see a link at the bottom of each news feed saying "send a hug to this person".

One way to create such an application is to display inside the IFrame of the application all of the user's news feeds through the API (and then I can add whatever I want). However, I would not like the user to enter the application tab each time he wants to send a hug, but to show it to him directly on his facebook's news feed page.

Thanks,

Meir

Answer (score 0):

read [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

```
Name    Description                      Permissions             Returns
link    The link attached to this post   Requires access_token   string containing the URL
name    The name of the link             Requires access_token   string
```